# Kalman Filter with dynamic estimated measurement variance

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I am implementing a simple Kalman Filter (Python) in order to filter the outputs of a Neural Network. This Neural Network not only provides me the output but also its variance (associated to the uncertainty of the model).

Currently I am using 2 KF to filter the 2 outputs, but they are totally independant. Since each single output has its own variance depending on the sample feeded into the input, I need to update the variance associated to each different measure on the way. I have tried to modify a KF code by adding the function "update_var". Right now is working, but **I don't know if I should call "update_var" before or after the method "input_DNN_prediction"**.

```
#KF Filtering for both outputs
for i in range(0,num_outputs):
    for iteration in range(1, iteration_count):
        #kalman_filter[i].update_var(outputs_dnn_var[iteration,i]) HERE?
        kalman_filter[i].input_DNN_prediction(outputs_dnn[iteration,i])
        #kalman_filter[i].update_var(outputs_dnn_var[iteration,i]) OR HERE?
        KF_estimate[iteration,i] = kalman_filter[i].get_latest_estimated_measurement()
```

More data: The data is stored such the output of the first sample is stored in "outputs_dnn[0,N_OUTPUT]" while its variance will be stored in  "outputs_dnn_var[0,N_OUTPUT]". In case the KF code is needed, here is the code:

```
class KalmanFilter(object):

    def __init__(self, process_variance, estimated_measurement_variance, posteri_estimate):
        self.process_variance = process_variance
        self.estimated_measurement_variance = estimated_measurement_variance
        self.posteri_estimate = posteri_estimate
        self.posteri_error_estimate = 1.0

    def update_var(self,estimated_measurement_variance):
        self.estimated_measurement_variance = estimated_measurement_variance

    def input_DNN_prediction(self, measurement):
        priori_estimate = self.posteri_estimate
        priori_error_estimate = self.posteri_error_estimate + self.process_variance

        blending_factor = priori_error_estimate / (priori_error_estimate + self.estimated_measurement_variance)
        self.posteri_estimate = priori_estimate + blending_factor * (measurement - priori_estimate)
        self.posteri_error_estimate = (1 - blending_factor) * priori_error_estimate

    def get_latest_estimated_measurement(self):
        return self.posteri_estimate
```

Thank you :)